# How to use wildcards in an active record where clause while protecting against sql injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

From the rails active record querying [guide on sql injection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

> This code is highly preferable:
>
> > Client.where("orders_count = ?", params[:orders])
>
> to this code:
>
> > Client.where("orders_count = #{params[:orders]}")

My problem is I want to use a LIKE clause with a wildcard. My old query looks like this -

```
User.where("first_name LIKE '%#{first_name}%'")
```

Which is vulnerable to sql injection, but if I do this:

```
User.where("first_name LIKE '%?%'", first_name)
```

Then the resulting sql looks like:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (first_name LIKE '%'michael'%')
```

which is invalid due to the extra single quotes.

What is the best way to use wildcards and a LIKE clause but also protect against sql injection attacks?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should modify your query like this

```
User.where("first_name LIKE (?)", "%#{first_name}%")
```

Comment: Is this vulnerable to SQL injection or does Rails sanitise it?

Comment: @KieranAndrews it seems to be vulnerable, because you can pass in more special characters like % and _, and they'll work.

Comment: Using `?` will work like a prepared statement and therefore the parameters are sanitized. Using `%` or `_` does not enable SQL injection.

Comment: Or to be more explicit:
 `User.where('first_name LIKE :first_name', first_name: "%#{first_name}%")`

Comment: It _is_ a form of SQL injection; consider someone who calls themselves `10%`. Underscores are also problematic given _not_ escaped by Rails out-of-the-box - they'd be treated as single character wildcards. The results of a query are likely to be far broader than intended when potentially user-supplied input could unwittingly contain data that gets treated as special query characters. This is *definitely very bad*! SOLUTION: In Rails >= 4.2, use `Model.sanitize_sql_like` - e.g. `User.where("first_name LIKE (?)", "%#{User.sanitize_sql_like(first_name)}%")` ==> `...WHERE (name LIKE ('%An\%%'))`.

Answer (score 2):

Update: Rails has improved this some.

Arel allows you to build queries with a simple DSL, and as a bonus, it's included in ActiveRecord. Here is an example for your use case.

```rb
User.where(User.arel_table[:first_name].matches("%#{first_name}%"))
```

This will do a case-insensitive search using `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE`.

Also want to note that Arel is internal to Rails and purposefully not exposed by the framework.